# JFrame de Eclipse importar a Netbeans no se ve

Tags: eclipse, netbeans-8.2, jframe, windowbuilder

Estoy realizando un proyecto de PGR para el instituto (1º DAM) en la cual tengo que utilizar interfaces gráficas (JFrame).

En mi ordenador lo hago con Eclipse, y posteriormente tengo que enviar el proyecto completo al profesor para que me lo corrija, sin embargo él utiliza Netbeans.

Cuando yo le envío mi proyecto y él lo importa en su ordenador, me dice que no tengo ninguna ventana hecha, osea que ve la clase pero, sin lo que yo he realizado en Eclipse.

Yo utilizo Eclipse versión 2020-03 (4.15.0) junto con [windowbuilder](/questions/tagged/windowbuilder) Nightly build 1.9.4.pre

La versión de Netbeans del profesor es 8.2

¿Alguien sabe porque pasa esto?
Gracias de antemano.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

En mi experiencia con ambos IDEs te puedo asegurar que lo mejor hablando de la interfaz gráfica es que deberías de hacerlo paso a paso con esto podrías asegurar que no importa como o donde sea compilado, siempre va a funcionar.

La razón del porque te está sucediendo esto en particular es por la diferencia de las herramientas que cada IDE, Netbeans para crear un frame y un par de botones genera hasta 50 líneas de código, eclipse por otro lado no genera las mismas líneas más bien hace quizá 30 esto ya podría hacer que las aplicaciones sean incompatibles para cada IDE

En conclusión revisa cómo puedes hacer tu interfaz paso a paso usando las librerías de swing o JFrame pero ve construyendo tu aplicación sin realmente usar las herramientas de los IDEs te comparto un articulo donde ejemplifica mucho más lo que te acabo de comentar

http://codejavu.blogspot.com/2013/10/eclipse-o-netbeans.html

Comment: Muchas gracias Felipe, intentaré hacer las interfaces como me comentas, así voy aprendiendo también. Un saludo.